# Validation for hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, time

I am new in C#.net. I want a validation for textbox which take only hh:mm:ss format.
Below is my code and its wroking. It gives output true 23:45:45 (example only) and also true for -23:45:45 (example only).
Now I want validation which return false for -23:45:45 (example only) because it is negative time. My running code does not work for negative time.

```
          IsTrue = ValidateTime(txtTime.Text);
            if (!IsTrue)
            {

                strErrorMsg += "\nPlease insert valid alpha time in hh:mm:ss formats";
                isValidate = false;
            }

  public bool ValidateTime(string time)
    {
        try
        {
            Regex regExp = new Regex(@"(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])");

            return regExp.IsMatch(time);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wouldn't use regular expressions at all - I'd simply try to parse the result as a `DateTime` with a custom format:

```
public bool ValidateTime(string time)
{
    DateTime ignored;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                  DateTimeStyles.None,
                                  out ignored);
}
```

(If you *really* want to stick with regular expressions, follow the answer from Mels. And I'd get rid of the pointless try/catch block, and probably just construct the regex once and reuse it, too.)

Comment: Jon, woulnd't [TimeSpan.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx) be better ?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, got my answer for negative hours :) +1. `TimeSpan.TryParse` would parse `-23:45:45` as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity: isn't there a more elegant way to indicate that we don't care about the actual parsed Date/Time? Other than using an `ignored` variable, that is?

Comment: @Mels: Yes, you could use NodaTime and a `LocalTimePattern`, then just return `ParseResult<LocalTime>.Success` :) (It would still have parsed the time, but it's clearer what you're trying to do with it.)

Comment: @Habib if you use custom format string as `h\\:mm\\:ss`, `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` will not parse `-23:45:45`

Answer (score 5):

Surround your regex with ^ at the start and $ at the end. These mark the beginning and end of the string and invalidate the match when there are any other characters.

Comment: But yours has the benefit of explaining what was wrong, which may well help the OP in other situations where a regex may actually be the right approach.